# How to display a long text without crashing Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to display a long text file (> 300kB) in a textarea.

Firefox and Edge have no problem with this at all, and can easily handle even larger files. But for some reason, in Chrome whenever the text contains too many of certain characters, the browser first freezes for several seconds and then crashes.

I've managed to create a sufficiently simple example to demonstrate the problem.

**If you are running Chrome, this tab will crash!** Don't say I didn't warn you.

```js
ta.value = '+'.repeat(500000);
```

```html
<textarea id='ta'></textarea>
```

Note that this only happens with certain characters, for example "+", but not with others like "q", etc. I'm not sure why.

My very simple question is how can I display some arbitrary long text in Chrome (not so long after all) like the one in my example without crashing my page? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the spell checker enabled by chance?

Comment: I have similar issue, I was trying to open a largish (>200MB) flat file in chorme and it crashed. Thanks to this page, I was able to open in other browsers. Please let me know if I'm the only one having this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :)

```js
ta.value = '+'.repeat(500000);
```

```html
<textarea id='ta' spellcheck="false" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Seems like this is a known issue as per the chromium bug comments [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237433).

Comment: Your link to the chromium bug from the original answer seemed useful, to me. How come you got rid of it?

Comment: Yey, this works but doesn't wrap the text. It shows everything in one line.

Comment: @J.Doe With the size of the input, changing `wrap="soft or hard"` would cause the memory issue as you've experienced. It eventually loads as wrapped but from a UI perspective isn't good.